# Log4net part in webconfig seems to be skipped

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, log4net

i try to include log4net in my project and have quite weird problem.

My  looks like below:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
    <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
```

and later in webconfig have:

```
  <log4net>
   (...)     
  </log4net>
```

Log4net doesn't work-file with errors isn't being created.

Now when i changed on purpose  config section for "microsoft.identityModel" (did some typo) and tried to go on my website -there is error.
But when i changed on purpose config section for "log4net" - website works well-looks like

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
```

is skipped or doesn't matter.
Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you initializing your logging?  Can you supply some sample logging code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have initialized your logger in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    ...
}
```

or use the assembly level attribute as illustrated in the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html):

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

You need to to tell log4net how it should configure itself somewhere. Global.asax is a good place for this.